# How can I include a progress indicator in Octave for parallel computations?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, progress-bar, octave

I wrote a function in Octave that uses `parcellfun` from the parallel package to split calculations up across multiple threads.

Even with multithreading, though, some calculations may take multiple hours to finish, so I would like to include some kind of progress indicator along the way. In the non-parallel version, it was fairly simple to just send the iteration counter to a waitbox object. The parallel version causes some problems.

So far, I have tried to write an extra function that could be called by each parallel child. That function is as follows. It uses persistent variables to try and keep information between the threads.

```
function parallelWaitbox(i, s)
    mlock();
    persistent n = 0;    % Completed calculations
    persistent m = 100;  % Total calculations
    persistent l = 0;    % Last percentage done (0:0.01:1)
    persistent h;        % Waitbox handle
    
    % Send 0 to initialize
    if(0 == i)
        n = 0;
        m = s;
        
        msg = sprintf("Total Operations: %i\r\n%i%% Complete",m,0);
        h = waitbar(0,msg);
    endif
    
    % Send 1 to increment
    if(1 == i)
        n++;
        % Special case: max
        if(n == m)
            msg = sprintf("Total Operations: %i\r\n100%% Complete",m);
            waitbar(1, h, msg);
        else
            p = floor(100*n/m)/100;
            if p > l
                msg = sprintf("Total Operations: %i\r\n%i%% Complete",m,p*100);
                waitbar(p,h,msg);
            endif
            l = p;
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

It is initialized with a call of `parallelWaitbox(0,max)` before the `parcellfun` call, and the parallel function calls `parallelWaitbox(1)` when it finishes. Unfortunately, because each thread is its own instance of Octave, they don't share this function, even when `mlock()` is called.

I tried to pass a handle to the `parallelWaitbox` function to the parallel function, in hopes it would help the different threads access the same version of the function, but it did not work.

I am not sure if passing a handle to the waitbox object would work, but even if it did there is no way to read from the waitbox that I am aware of, so the problem of keeping track of the current state would remain.

I know that I *could* use a for loop to split my `parcellfun` call up to 100 chunks, but I'd really rather avoid slowing my processing down. If there's a better way to do this, I'd love to know about it. I am not tied to the waitbox object if there is an alternative.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/parallel/function/parcellfun.html): "If option VerboseLevel is set to 1 (default is 0), progress messages are printed to stderr".

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed that bit. No waitbox, but it gets the job done just fine.